# Indefinite integral. Where is the mistake?

Tags: calculus, fake-proofs

The problem was to compute $I=\int x^2\sin^{-1}(x)\ dx$

(where $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse function of $\sin(x)$).

The answer of my students: firstly, we put $u=\sin^{-1}(x)$, so $x=\sin(u)$ and $dx=\cos(u)\ du$. Thus, the given integral is $$I=\int u\cos(u)\sin^2(u)\ du$$

Now, we do the substitution $v=\pi-u$, so $dv=-du$ and
 $$I=-\int (\pi-v)\cos(\pi-v)\sin^2(\pi-v)\ dv$$ Since $\cos(\pi-v)=-\cos(v)$ and $\sin(\pi-v)=\sin(v)$, it follows that $$I=\int (\pi-v)\cos(v)\sin^2(v)\ dv$$

As a consequence, $$I=\int\pi\cos(v)\sin^2(v)\ dv-I=\frac{\pi\sin^3(v)}{3}-I=\frac{\pi x^3}{3}-I$$.

Finally, $$I=\frac{\pi x^3}{6}+C$$

This result is obviously false but where is the mistake? My only guess is that $u\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $u\in(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2})$, so $\int v\cos(v)\sin^2(v)\ dv$ is not equal to $I$ but I am not totally convinced.

Comment: Does $\sin^{-1}(x)$ mean the inverse of $\sin$ function or $1/\sin(x)$ to you?

Comment: $ \arcsin(x) $.

Comment: $\sin^{-1}$ is the inverse of $\sin$, i.e. the $\arcsin$ function. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Is there a factor of $\pi$ missing in the result line as well, or just a typo?

Comment: Yes, just a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: This is one of best fake proofs I have ever seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me explain it in a simpler way using a ridiculous example. Consider we want to compute the integrate for an even function $f(x)=f(-x)$. We write
$$I(x)=\int f(x)dx\tag{1}$$
Substitute $y=-x$ into (1)
$$I(y)=\int f(-y)d(-y)=-\int f(y)dy\tag{2}$$
Then the ridiculous conclusion isdrawn
$$I(y)=-I(y)\Longrightarrow I(y)=0$$
So the problem is, instead of $\int f(x)dx=\int f(y)dy$, but on **the confusion of value $x$ and variable $x$**. The correct version should be
$$I(x)=I(y)|_{y=-x}\neq I(-x)\\
I(y)=-I(\xi)|_{\xi=y}\neq-I(y)\tag{*}$$
One more clearer example, take $f(x)=x^2$. One will see
$$I(x)=^{(1)}\frac13x^3=I(y)|_{y=-x}=^{(2)}-\frac13y^3|_{y=-x}\neq I(-x)=^{(1)}-\frac13x^3\\
I(y)=^{(2)}-\frac13y^3=-I(\xi)|_{\xi=y}=^{(1)}-\frac13\xi^3|_{\xi=y}\neq-I(y)=^{(2)}\frac13y^3$$

Comment: if (1) and (2) represent the same integral, is it possible to replace x by y in the LHS but by -y in the RHS in equation (2) ?

Answer (score 6):

This is a fantastic error. Basically the problem is that $$\int v \cos(v) \sin^2(v)\,dv \neq \int u\cos(u)\sin^2(u)\,du.$$  The reason is because you have two indefinite integrals in *different variables*.  Here is a simpler example: we do not have $$\int x\,dx= \int v\,dv,$$ as $$\int x\,dx=\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1$$ and $$\int v\,dv=\frac{v^2}{2}+C_2$$ for these integrals to be equal, we would need $x^2 = v^2 +C_3$, and that is not necessarily true. In fact, in this example, the only possible choice is $v=x$, and $C_1=C_2$. Imagine $v=x^2$—then it is clearly false!

Comment: I think i get it, one $I$ is in terms of dx and the other $I$ in terms of dv, and that put together in one equation. Something to think about...not a common error but indeed a fantastic one

Comment: I disagree. There aren't any problems with this sort of manipulation, as long as you treat the substituted variables as functions of the original variables (with the brackets omitted). With your example, to get $\int x\,dx=\int v\,dv$, you must do a substitution $v=x$, $dv=dx$. Thus $v=v(x)=x$ is a function. At the end you get $\int x\,dx=v^2/2+c$, but this is alright, because $v=x$, and to get it back in terms of $x$ you just substitute to get $\int x\,dx=x^2/2+c$, with no ambiguity.

Comment: The issue comes in when you need those implicit brackets. The OP has, after the $x\mapsto u$ substitution, $I(u)=\int u\cos u\sin^2 u\,du$. With the $v$ substitution, this becomes $I(u)=\int(\pi-v)\cos v\sin^2 v\,dv=\frac{\pi}3\sin^3[v(u)]+I(v(u))$, and the error comes from conflating $I(u)$ with $I(v(u))$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: I don't understand what you are trying to say. $v(x)=x$, and $v(x)=\sqrt{x^2+C}$ are the _only_ functions for which equality holds in the example I gave, so in general it is false.

Comment: @Eric You imposed the condition $v=x$ when you performed the initial substitution to get $\int x\,dx=\int v\,dv$, so there is no "in general" here -- you already know $v(x)=x$, so $x^2+c=v^2+c$ is automatically satisfied.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: Again, I don't understand what you are saying. We don't already know that $v(x)=x$. The point is that given some $v$ and $x$ whose relation has not been specified, we cannot conclude that $\int v dv=\int xdx$, as this only holds in select few cases.

Comment: @EricNaslund The last sentence you said is correct. $\int v\,dv=\int x\,dx$ is not true for arbitrary $v$ and $x$ any more than $f(x)=f(v)$ is. However, the whole point of integration by substitution is to prove the equality of two integrals in different variables, and so we start from the definition $v=x$, and substitution allows us to claim that $\int v\,dv=\int x\,dx$. This is not a general claim, but rather one predicated on $v=x$, and surely you wouldn't dispute that $x=v\Rightarrow f(x)=f(v)$ based on the fact that $f(x)=f(v)$ is almost never true, except in the special case $v=x$.