# What is the inverse/opposite of a double integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am currently taking Calc 3 and we just finished our unit on double/triple integrals. I started thinking about a problem back from AP Physics (where my teacher did an impressive amount of hand waving to somehow avoid directly explaining vector calculus when discussing Maxwell's equations, leading to me spending an entire semester confused about what the heck flux was supposed to be or why it should matter), which basically boils down to $\iiint_D{F(x, y, z)}{dV}=Q(D)$. In Calc 1 and 2, if you have an equation of the form $\int{f(x)}{dx}=g(x)$, then you can take the "inverse integral" (i.e. derivative with respect to x) of both sides, which gives $f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}g(x)$. However, I cannot seem to figure out what the analogue of this would be for a double or triple integral. What is the opposite/inverse operation for a double or triple integral over some domain $D$?

Comment: There isn't any, this is specific to one dimension only

Comment: @NinadMunshi Shouldn't there at least be some way to define a new operation such that it is the inverse of a double integral over some particular region D? Even if it isn't an analytic operation, it still should exist. Much like the function xe^x doesn't have an algebraic inverse, but we can still define a non-elementary function W(x) such that it has the property W(xe^x) = x for all real numbers x.

Comment: Both $\int_0^1\mathrm dx=1$ and $\int_0^12x\,\mathrm dx=1$. Are you suggesting there should be some way of recovering the integrand of a definite integral given its value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's convenient but misleading to write $\int f(x) \, dx = g(x)$. The RHS is a function of $x$ but the LHS is not until you write down some bounds of integration, and once you do the inner $x$ has been integrated over so it's a "dummy variable" that has nothing to do with the $x$ on the RHS. Less ambiguous is to write

$$\int_a^x f(t) \, dt = g(x)$$

which makes the dependence on $x$ of the LHS clear and emphasizes that the variable being integrated over is a dummy variable.

This is not just pedantry; the point of doing this is to emphasize what changes when you move from integrals to double integrals. To think of a double integral as a function of two variables, rather than just as a function of a region being integrated over, we need to pick regions to integrate over that are defined by two parameters. An easy choice is a rectangle $[a, x] \times [b, y]$, which lets us write expressions like

$$\int_{t=b}^y \int_{s=a}^x f(s, t) \, ds \, dt = g(x, y)$$

and if we set things up like this we can recover $f$ by differentiating twice, using the fundamental theorem of calculus twice:

$$f(x, y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} g(x, y).$$

This generalizes to $n$ dimensions too. But it's worth emphasizing that in order to do this we had to choose to integrate over rectangles, and there are lots of other choices of how to parameterize regions to integrate over that we could make instead.

Comment: Ahh, I see. If you're given any particular domain D to take a double integral over, is there a way to find a corresponding inverse then? For instance, say that D is the disk {(x, y) in R^2 | x^2 + y^2 <= 1}.

Comment: @Null: if you fix the domain then the output of integration over that domain is just a number. That's not enough information to recover a function from. This is already true in one dimension.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I guess to ask a slightly different question, if Q(D) = a triple integral over D of some function F(x, y, z), how would you interpret the function F(x, y, z) qualitatively in relation to Q(D)? I realize this is not exactly a rigorous discussion, but I guess my question is less what F(x, y, z) is and more what F(x, y, z) *be*

Comment: @Null: that's a very different question. Maybe the simplest "physical" interpretation is that $F$ describes a "density" and the triple integral describes a "total mass." This interpretation only makes sense if $F$ is non-negative, though.

Comment: @Null: I guess you're trying to understand something related to the divergence theorem, is that right? If so there's a pretty good discussion at the Wikipedia article of what the volume integral of the divergence means: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem

Comment: It seems to me that a similar argument could be made that the notation $\frac{df}{dx} = g(x)$ is misleading for the same reason (on the LHS, "$dx$" is essentially a dummy variable that's being taken to zero), and you should really write something like $\frac{df(x)}{dx}|_{x = y} = g(y)$. It's just that the standard Leibnitz notation for the derivative seems less likely to trip people up in practice. I don't think there's any "fundamental" difference between the correctness of the two notations, just that the integral notation is (slightly) more likely to lead to confusion in practice.

Comment: Although I personally remember that when I was just learning calculus for the first time, I was very confused by the fact that the "$x$"'s on the two sides are conceptually very different, and I think that the more pedantic notation might have been pedagogically useful. This is pretty clear when you expand out (one possible) full definition of the derivative:
$f'(x_0) := \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0}.$

Comment: Similarly, the standard notation leads to ambiguous questions like "If $f(x) = x^2$ and $x = 5$ then what is $df/dx$?" It's clear to an expert what question is being asked here in a pedagogical context, but it's understandable for a beginner to reason that "$f(x) = 25$ so $df/dx = d/dx\ 25 = 0$ so the answer is 0." Using two different variables would help eliminate this ambiguity.

Comment: I don't understand why $\int f(x) dx$ is not a function of $x$ (precisely, a family of functions of $x$ defined up to a constant on every interval). It is not true that $\int f(x) dx=\int f(t) tdt$ for definite integrals (see this old question of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547487/indefinite-integral-where-is-the-mistake)

Answer (score 1):

To complement  Qiaochu Y. excellent explanation  note that,  same as we write
$$
\eqalign{
  & \int {f(x)dx}  = g(x) = \int_{t = a}^x {f(t)dt}  + c
 = \int\limits_{t \in \left[ {a,x} \right]} {f(t)dt}  + c\quad  \Rightarrow \quad   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad d\int_{t = a}^x {f(t)dt}  = \int\limits_{t \in \left[ {x,x + dx} \right]} {f(t)dt}
  = f(x)dx = {d \over {dx}}g(x)dx \cr} 
$$
with all cautions as for continuity, and with the algebraic meaning for negative $dx$,

then, specially in physics, we often write
$$
\eqalign{
  & \int\!\!\!\int\limits_A {f(x,y)dxdy}  = \int\!\!\!\int\limits_A {f(x,y)\delta A}  = g(A)\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \delta \int\!\!\!\int\limits_A {f(x,y)\delta A}  = \int\!\!\!\int\limits_{\delta A} {f(x,y)dxdy}
  = {d \over {dA}}g(A)\,\delta A \cr} 
$$
where  the $\delta A$ is also taken with the algebraic sign.

[image: Delta_Int_Mult_1]

From here we reach to [Stoke's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem).